# PDO works outside a function, doesn't work within

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I'm trying to validate login in PDO, but it doesn't work while it's inside a function. I've tried adding the `$db` to the function as well, doesn't help. It echoes "bad" no matter what happens, if I remove it from the function, it works fine with the exact same code. Here's the whole thing:

```
function logIn($db)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE Username = :user AND Usernameclean = :userclean AND Password = :pass");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user", $user);
        $stmt->bindParam(":userclean", $userclean);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pass", $pass);
        $stmt->execute();
        $status = (bool) $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
        if ($status)
        {
            echo "good";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "bad";
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "There was a problem connecting to this database.";
    $e->getMessage();
    }
}
logIn($db);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be passing the `$user`, `$userclean` or `$pass` variables.
Make sure you pass those to your function (or, at the very least, globalise them)

Edit: John beat me to it!

Answer (score 4):

You must also pass other variables you are using inside the function to that function.

Therefore, the correct function would be:

```
function logIn($db, $user, $userclean, $pass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE Username = :user AND Usernameclean = :userclean AND Password = :pass");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user", $user);
        $stmt->bindParam(":userclean", $userclean);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pass", $pass);
        $stmt->execute();
        $status = (bool) $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
        if ($status)
        {
            echo "good";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "bad";
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "There was a problem connecting to this database.";
    $e->getMessage();
    }
}
logIn($db, $user, $userclean, $pass);
```

Answer (score 3):

You remember to pass your `$db` variable to the function but forgot about `$user`, `$userclean`, and `$pass` so they are not available to your function (they are out of scope).

Fortunately this is easy to fix:

```
function logIn($db, $user, $userclean, $pass)
```

Comment: Thank you! First function ever, so I didn't figure out there's a scope. Wonderful.